# Inquiry about kernel programming

Tags: kernel

First,Let me introduce myself.
This is Monika sHarma , pursuing B.Tech(Final year-Computer science)
I want to know about Kernel level programming.
Is there anyone who can tell me how can i know about it more down to the core?
Is C language sufficient for learning the same?
It will better for me if it doesn't require LINUX.
How can I get matter on it?Please let me know the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know

- C language
- IA-32 architecture, instruction set and programming. (if you are programming for this architecture)

Developing platform depends on you. I do not have any experience developing in Windows Platform, but i can provide the tools which are generally required

- A compiler (gcc in my case)
- An assembler (nasm in my case)
- A linked (the GNU linker `ld` in my case)
- A bootloader (if you do not make one yourself (i have used GRUB))
- A VM (Bochs) for testing the os

Going down to core would take real time. You can refer OS books. For community support you can get into:

- http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page
- http://www.osdever.net/

Actually you need to get into the stuff yourself.